# AngularJS - BottomSheet not working. "is not a function"

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, mddialog

Im having some difficulties with `openBottomSheet` API.

**This is my HTML:**

```
<md-button aria-label="Open Settings" ng-click="openBottomSheet($event)">
   <ng-md-icon icon="more_vert"></ng-md-icon>
</md-button>
```

**This opens the openBottomSheet inside my controller that looks like this:**

```
$scope.openBottomSheet = function() {
    $mdBottomSheet.show({
        template: '<md-bottom-sheet>' +
        'Hello! <md-button ng-click="closeBottomSheet()">Close</md-button>' +
        '</md-bottom-sheet>'
    })
    // Fires when the hide() method is used
        .then(function() {
            console.log('You clicked the button to close the bottom sheet!');
        })
        // Fires when the cancel() method is used
        .catch(function() {
            console.log('You hit escape or clicked the backdrop to close.');
        });
};
$scope.closeBottomSheet = function($scope, $mdBottomSheet) {
    $mdBottomSheet.hide();
}
```

This is based on the documentation, so why cannot i get it to work in my project?

**Controller injection:**

```
.controller('containerCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', '$http', '_', '$q', '$state', '$mdBottomSheet','$mdSidenav', function ($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $http, $q, $state,$mdBottomSheet,$mdSidenav) {
```

This is my error:

> main.min.js:3 TypeError: c.show is not a function

```
 `c.show` is this line in controller: `$mdBottomSheet.show({` (minified version)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `-` in the controller injection. Both string array injection and service injection should be equal and same order.

```
.controller('containerCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', '$http',  '$q', '$state', '$mdBottomSheet','$mdSidenav', 
function ($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $http, $q, $state,$mdBottomSheet,$mdSidenav) {
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked now! but why is "underscore" causing the mdBottomSheet not to work properly? i added it in last now but the mdBottomSheet works but not accurate. The sheet has wrong css when underscore(_) is added. why?

Comment: @Asim your injection order wasn't matching: `'$http', '_', '$q'` - `$http, $q`. So everything shifted by one: `$q` became `'_'` and `mdBottomSheet` became `'$state'`. So it couldn't do `$state.show()`